# In Pig getting error as 'Error compiling operator POLocalRearrange'

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am practicing on cloudera yarn VMware Player(non commercial use).
My script in pig is,

`a1 = load '/user/training/my_hdfs/id' using PigStorage('\t') as(id:int,name:chararray,desig:chararray);
a2 = load '/user/training/my_hdfs/trips' using PigStorage('\t') as(id:int,place:chararray,no_trips:int);
a3 = join a1 by id,a2 by id;
a4 = group a3 by a1::id; 
illustrate a4;`

After illustrate it is showing message as,

`2017-08-21 07:52:11,926 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Exception : Error compiling operator POLocalRearrange`

Dataset is,

`Table id
101 aaa executive
102 bbb manager
104 hhh manager
106 ccc trainee
109 hhh trainee`

`Table trips
101 pune    1
101 hyd 2
102 pune    2
102 hyd 3
102 bang    4`

Answer (score 0):

When i tried running you program with the provided data,i too get some error as the delimiter in you files is not consistent. Some where its space and some where its tab(may be its because copy pasting). I make the delimiter universal(using tab) and everything works perfectly fine.

Try to use dump a1 or dump a2 and see if you can see data in correct columns.
For me it worked perfect after making delimiter universal and illustrate a4 gives below output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| a1     | id:int     | name:chararray     | desig:chararray     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 101        | aaa                | executive           |
|        | 101        | aaa                | executive           |
------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
| a2     | id:int     | place:chararray     | no_trips:int     |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 101        | pune                | 1                |
|        | 101        | hyd                 | 2                |
----------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| a3     | a1::id:int     | a1::name:chararray     | a1::desig:chararray     | a2::id:int     | a2::place:chararray     | a2::no_trips:int     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 101            | aaa                    | executive               | 101            | pune                    | 1                    |
|        | 101            | aaa                    | executive               | 101            | hyd                     | 2                    |
|        | 101            | aaa                    | executive               | 101            | pune                    | 1                    |
|        | 101            | aaa                    | executive               | 101            | hyd                     | 2                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| a4     | group:int     | a3:bag{:tuple(a1::id:int,a1::name:chararray,a1::desig:chararray,a2::id:int,a2::place:chararray,a2::no_trips:int)}                                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 101           | {(101, ..., 1), ..., (101, ..., 2)}                                                                                                               |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi user3359790, I really thank you for your reply,data is actually consistent on my pc, in copy paste here it became inconsistent,I tried many things at last I uninstalled my VM player ,yarn and again reinstalled everything.To my surprise it worked normally and gave output as you have shown.I did not understand  what was the problem but uninstalling and again installing everything fresh solved the issue.I again thank  you for the concern you have shown.